# Stripe: Pre-fill card name with customer's name

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am starting with Stripe Checkout. I first create a customer and check on the Stripe dashboard that name and email appear. But at the checkout page with debit card details, only the email is pre-filled:

[image: screenshot of checkout page]

The server-side code to create the checkout session is:

```js
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      customer: user.stripe_customer_id,
      mode: 'setup',
      success_url: config.public_domain + '/sucesso?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      cancel_url: config.public_domain + '/cancelar',
    });
```

I have tried adding fields such as `cardholder`, `cardname`, `cardName`, `name`: all of these fail.

Is it possible to pre-fill the card name from the customer's name, even if they have to change it to match the cardholder's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to pre-fill that field.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Do you have a reference from the documentation?

Comment: It's not explicitly stated in the docs but there's no such parameter for you to prefill. Even if the Customer `name` is defined, it wouldn't prefill the name on the card in Checkout.

Comment: It is possible to pre-fill that field with js or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to easily prepopulate that field:

```
$("#name").val("foo bar");
```

Comment: This checkout page is on Stripe's servers. I don't see how I could run jquery or JavaScript on it.

Comment: There is a way to set it up so that you use their APIs, but the payment page runs on your own server. This is what I do.

Comment: Do you use Stripe Elements to have the payment page on your own server?